# Ontario resident working contract job in British Columbia

Tags: taxes, canada, small-business, corporation

If my corporation is registered in Ontario and I am an Ontario resident, then if I take a contract in Vancouver, will it be legal? Do I pay taxes once for British Columbia and once for Ontario?